# Emacs - setting a buffer variable in an init file

Tags: variables, emacs, buffer

I need to set the buffer-variable `bidi-display-reordering` in all the buffers... for some reason, its default value isn't correct. It's a pain to do it in each and every buffer I open, so I tried to put the following line in the file  `.emacs.d/init.el`:

```lisp
(setq bidi-display-reordering nil)
```

I then exited Emacs and re-started it, but it didn't work. What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: The default value certainly *is* correct.  As the docstring says, "Setting this to nil is intended for use in debugging the display code.  Don’t set to nil in normal sessions, as that is not supported."

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `setq` you need to use `setq-default`. From `C-h f setq-default`:

> `(setq-default [VAR VALUE]...)`

> Set the default value of variable VAR to VALUE. VAR, the variable name, is literal (not evaluated). VALUE is an expression: it is evaluated and its value returned. The default value of a variable is seen in buffers that do not have their own values for the variable.

It has the same syntax as `setq`, so just put instead:

```
(setq-default bidi-display-reordering nil)
```

Comment: ... but as @phils points out in a comment, setting `bidi-display-reordering` to `nil` is a *BAD* idea (except in the *very* unlikely case that the OP is debugging display code). So although the answer is technically correct, it is not clear that it would *help* the OP - in fact, the opposite is the more likely scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if setting this variable is a BAD idea, as the comments say, how then should I solve my problem? my files have both English and right-to-left text, and this text is shown backward (each word is spelled backward).